# How to combine first element of one array with first element of second array and first element of first array with second element of second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays with different length and the number of items in each array is dynamic. I want to combine the first element of one array with first element of second array and first element of first array with second element of second array and so on.for example:

The first array is `['a','b','c']`
The second array is `['1','2]`

Finally, I need the result to look like this:

```
['a-1','a-2','b-1','b-2','c-1','c-2]
```

Comment: This looks more like each element from the first array with each element from the second array.

Comment: const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const array2 = ['1', '2'];
const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    const combinedElement = array1[i] + '-' + array2[j];
    result.push(combinedElement);
  }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to iterate over each element of `array1` and use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) on array2:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = ['1', '2'];

const resArray = arr1.flatMap(item1 =>
  arr2.map(item2 => `${item1}-${item2}`)
);

console.log(resArray); //["a-1","a-2","b-1", "b-2","c-1","c-2"]
```

You can achieve the result using [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement) as well:

```js
const arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const arr2 = ['1', '2'];
const resArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    const elem = arr1[i] + '-' + arr2[j];
    resArray.push(elem);
  }
}
console.log(resArray); //["a-1","a-2","b-1", "b-2","c-1","c-2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To combine the elements of the first array with the elements of the second array as described, **you can use array methods like** `map` and `flatMap` in **JavaScript**.

```
const firstArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const secondArray = ['1', '2'];

const result = firstArray.flatMap((element) => {
  return secondArray.map((value) => `${element}-${value}`);
});

console.log(result);
//Output : [ 'a-1', 'a-2', 'b-1', 'b-2', 'c-1', 'c-2' ]
```